# yii 2 pagination is losing filter data in the model

Tags: yii, pagination, yii2

Right, I have a list view that shows content from my database. The pagination works great with this. However as soon as i apply filters to my data provider and try to paginate to the second page for example, it forgets all filters and goes to the 2nd page of all the content.

has anyone experienced this?

If you need code please do ask and i will provide but it would be a hell of a lot to go through

View:

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class="top-tr">
                <th width="50%">Case name</th>
                <th>Primary citation</th>
                <th>Bailii.org</th>
                <th>Adj.co.uk</th>
                <?php if(isset($chapters)) { ?>
                <th>Para(s)</th>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if(!isset($chapters)) {

                echo listView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'itemView' => function ($model, $chapters) {
                        return '<tr><td><a href="/web/cases/view?id='. $model->case_id .'">' . $model->name . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $model->getCitation() . '</td>' .    
                        (strtolower($model->bailli) != "not available" ? '<td><a class="external-link" href=' . $model->bailli . ' target="_blank">Visit site</a></td>' : '<td></td>') .
                        (strtolower($model->adjudication_URL) != "not available" ? '<td><a class="external-link" href=' . $model->adjudication_URL . ' target="_blank">Visit site</a></td></tr>' : '<td></td></tr>');
                    },
                ]);

            } else {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($chapters);
                echo "</pre>";
                if(isset($category) && $category !== null) {
                    echo '<h3>Sub-section: ' . $category[0]['name'] . '</h3>';

                }elseif(isset($subcategory) && $subcategory !== null){
                    echo '<h3>Section: ' . $subcategory[0]['name'] . '</h3>';
                }elseif(isset($firstcategory) && $firstcategory !== null){
                    echo '<h3>Chapter: ' . $firstcategory[0]['name'] . '</h3>';
                }
                $i=0;


                echo '<div class="summary">Showing <b>1-' . count($dataProvider->models) . '</b> of <b>' . $dataProvider->pagination->totalCount . '</b> items.</div>';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($dataProvider->getPagination());
                echo '</pre>';

                echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
                    'pagination' => $dataProvider->getPagination(),
                ]);


                foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td><a href="/web/cases/view&id='. $model->case_id .'">' . $model->name . '</a></td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $model->getCitation() . '</td>';
                    echo ($model->bailli != "Not available" ? '<td><a class="external-link" href=' . $model->bailli . ' target="_blank">Visit site</a></td>' : '<td></td>');
                    echo ($model->adjudication_URL != "Not available" ? '<td><a class="external-link" href=' . $model->adjudication_URL . ' target="_blank">Visit site</a></td>' : '<td></td>');
                    echo '<td><a href="/web/cases/view?id='. $model->case_id .'#paragraph">' . $chapters[$i] .'</a></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    $i++;
                }
            } ?>
        </table>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    if(Yii::$app->user->identity->approved !== 1) {
        return $this->redirect(['site/notapproved']);
    }

    $model = new Cases;
    $searchModel = new CaseSearch();// This is the data to be displayed in gridview
    $searchModelChapter = new CaseChapter;// This for when searching with categories
    //$test1 = $test->find()->asArray()->all();
    $mainCategory = Category::find()->all();// This is grabing the first category list to populate first drop down
    $subCategory = Subcategory::find()->all();
    $childCategory = Childcategory::find()->all();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);// This is the filter options for the gridview

    $page = 50;
    if (null !== Yii::$app->request->get('pageSize')) {
        $page = Yii::$app->request->get('pageSize');
        if ($page == "all") {
            $page = 10000;
        }
    }

    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=$page;
    $dataProvider->sort = array('defaultOrder' => [
        'name' => SORT_ASC
    ]);
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $post = $request->post();//$post now takes place of normal $_POST array;
    $get = $request->get();


    /*
    /*
     * This deals with the post values when the drop down lists are chosen and submitted via POST
     */
    if($searchModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

        //The first category will always be set
        if(isset($post['CaseSearch']['category'])){
            if(isset($post['CaseSearch']['subcategory']) && !isset($post['CaseSearch']['childcategory'])){
                $childCategories = new Childcategory;
                $childcategories = $childCategories->findChildcategoryBySecond($post['CaseSearch']['subcategory']);
                $childcategories = $childCategories->findChildcategoryIds($childcategories);
                $dataProvider = $searchModelChapter->findChapters($childcategories);
                $category = null;
                $firstcategory = null;
                $subcategory_id = $post['CaseSearch']['subcategory'];
                $sub_case_chapter = new CaseChapter;
                $subcategory = $sub_case_chapter->findChapterSubCategories($subcategory_id);
            }

            if(!isset($post['CaseSearch']['childcategory']) && !isset($post['CaseSearch']['subcategory'])){
                $childCategories = new Childcategory;
                $childcategories = $childCategories->findChildcategoryByFirst($post['CaseSearch']['category']);
                $childcategories = $childCategories->findChildcategoryIds($childcategories);
                $dataProvider = $searchModelChapter->findChapters($childcategories);
                $category = null;
                $subcategory = null;
                $firstcategory_id = $post['CaseSearch']['category'];
                $first_case_chapter = new CaseChapter;
                $firstcategory = $first_case_chapter->findChapterFirstCategories($firstcategory_id);
            }

            if(isset($post['CaseSearch']['childcategory'])){
                $childcategory_id = $post['CaseSearch']['childcategory'];
            }else{
                $childcategory_id = null;
            }

            if($childcategory_id !== null){
                $dataProvider = $searchModelChapter->findChapters($childcategory_id);
                $case_chapter = new CaseChapter;
                $category = $case_chapter->findChapterCategories($childcategory_id);
                $subcategory = null;
                $firstcategory = null;
            }

        }elseif(isset($post['CaseSearch']['childcategory']) && !isset($CaseSearch['CaseSearch']['category']) && !isset($CaseSearch['CaseSearch']['subcategory'])){
            $searchModelChapter = new CaseChapter;
            $dataProvider = $searchModelChapter->findChapters($post['CaseSearch']['childcategory']);
            $category = $searchModelChapter->findChapterCategories($post['CaseSearch']['childcategory']);
            $subcategory = null;
            $firstcategory = null;
        }elseif(isset($post['CaseSearch']['subcategory']) && !isset($CaseSearch['CaseSearch']['category']) && !isset($CaseSearch['CaseSearch']['childcategory'])){
            $searchModelChapter = new CaseChapter;
            $childcat = new Childcategory;
            $categories = $childcat->findChildcategoryBySecond($post['CaseSearch']['subcategory']);
            $category_ids = $childcat->findChildcategoryIds($categories);
            $dataProvider = $searchModelChapter->findChapters($category_ids);
            $category = null;
            $subcategory = $searchModelChapter->findChapterCategories($post['CaseSearch']['subcategory']);
            $firstcategory = null;
        }else{
            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'mainCategory' => $mainCategory,
                'subcategory' => $subCategory,// to supply all subcategories in drop down list
                'childcategory' => $childCategory,// to supply all childcategories in drop down list
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }


        $dataProvider[0]->pagination->pageSize=50;

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider[0],
            'mainCategory' => $mainCategory,
            'chapters' => $dataProvider[1],
            'category' => $category,
            'subcategory' => $subcategory,
            'firstcategory' => $firstcategory,
            'subcategory' => $subCategory,// to supply all subcategories in drop down list
            'childcategory' => $childCategory,// to supply all childcategories in drop down list
        ]); 
    }
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'mainCategory' => $mainCategory,
        'subcategory' => $subCategory,
        'childcategory' => $childCategory,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: You should provide code, unfortunately.

Comment: @robsch i have updated with code

Comment: Is the whole code necessary to find an answer? Could you reduce it?

Comment: Still too much code for me. I'm wondering who would have fun to read that and find out what your code actually does. You should reduce it drastically and provide more detailed information (what does the user enter, which URL get generated, which if/else branches are used...). Btw, I think it is not good to have so much code in a single action - IMO you should improve that too.